# Trait conflict between impl for T and something of FnMut() -> T

Tags: rust, traits

So i have this trait for filling an array from various types, however i get conflicting implementations for `T` and `F: FnMut() -> T`. I'm guessing the only point of overlap would be the case of `F: FnMut() -> F`, in which case the function `F` returns itself and equals `T`. Essentially, the compiler considers the possiblity of `F` being an `FnMut() -> (FnMut() -> (FnMut() -> ...))`.

Here's the code, which will not compile:

```rust
pub trait ArrayFill<T, const LENGTH: usize>
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH];
}

impl<T, const LENGTH: usize> ArrayFill<T, LENGTH> for T
where
    T: Copy
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH]
    {
        [self; LENGTH]
    }
}
impl<F, T, const LENGTH: usize> ArrayFill<T, LENGTH> for F
where
    F: FnMut() -> T
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH]
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I've tried using an auto-trait with a negative implementation for `F: FnMut() -> F`, but even then conflict persists, as i don't think the compiler is able to reason properly with the negative implementation. The attempted solution is shown below:

```rust
#![feature(auto_traits)]
#![feature(negative_impls)]

auto trait NotFnMutToSelf {}
impl<F> !NotFnMutToSelf for F
where
    F: FnMut() -> F {}

pub trait ArrayFill<T, const LENGTH: usize>
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH];
}

impl<T, const LENGTH: usize> ArrayFill<T, LENGTH> for T
where
    T: Copy + NotFnMutToSelf
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH]
    {
        [self; LENGTH]
    }
}
impl<F, T, const LENGTH: usize> ArrayFill<T, LENGTH> for F
where
    F: FnMut() -> T
{
    fn fill_into_array(self) -> [T; LENGTH]
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I don't think specialization could solve it, because although the implementations overlap, neither of them overlap the other completely.

Any idea how to resolve this conflict?

Comment: @isactfa FnMut(...) -> ... is just syntax sugar for FnMut<..., Output = ...>, which is a trait, not a type.

Comment: Yes. The conflic occurs because the set T where T: Copy and F where F: FnMut() -> T overlaps in the special case where the type (T or F): FnMut() -> Self + Copy. To resolve the conflict while still using generics for the implementation, i need to find a way to add a trait bound to T or F in one or both of the implementations so that they no longer overlap.

Comment: @isaactfa Yes, but `ArrayFill<T> for T` and `ArrayFill<T> for FnMut() -> T` overlap only when `F = T`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh, I completely overlooked that `T` was constrained by the trait, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. [A situation like that was even described in the specialization RFC, as something the proposed RFC *will not* solve](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html#limitations).

Comment: Thanks. The ByNeed example is pretty much the same as mine.

Comment: I've managed to solve a similar kind of conflict in the case where the partial overlap between the implementations consist of a finite set of structs. Then you can unimplement the auto-trait as shown in my example, but for a non-generic type, somehow the auto trait with a negative impl works as a "negative bound" and the compiler understands that the otherwise overlapping types do not implement the auto-trait. This does not work here when the auto trait is unimplemented for a generic type.